# CSS percentage width resize based on window

Tags: css, resize, media-queries

This probably was answered somewhere, but I can't find it :s

My question is about dynamic resizing of divs based in percentages.

Please look at code example below for the examples and possible solutions I made.
I ask if there is a better way to do resizing?

More detailed explanation:

Say I am writing a plugin that people can insert in their pages. *(Imagine login form)*.
I go ahead and design the plugin's divs. I use media queries to achieve desired look for different devices. I work on a div straight inside of a 'body' element.
I use **percentages** for design (I like percentages). Say I set div to **80% width**.

Now I give this plugin to the user. User goes ahead and puts the plugin's div inside of another 
div that is **100px** in width. Now everything looks awful. *(80% of 100px is not a lot [80px])*.
And of course I want user to put my plugin inside of whatever small-width divs that he have.

The solutions I saw so far to this problem was to create a holder div of certain width - say hardcode 300px. *(ex - jQuery UI's Datepicker div; Meteor's login widget div)*. And then code to it always knowing the 300px width that I set before is not going to change.

But I don't know how good of a solution this is.

Moreover if I decide to go with hard-coding width, my plugin would need width of ~ 1000px. Because I want div to resize with **media queries**. 
And if I go with hard-coding width (say holder div of 1000px width) and put it on a page, the page will have **horizontal scrolling**. And you cannot simply hide holder div (parent div) and have child to show at the same time. So this requires setting position:relative for holder (parent) div, putting it outside of window, and use same for child div - position:relative with same offset in opposite direction of parent offset.

I hope I am being clear so far and have not confused you!

A code example to illustrate what I am talking about:
**http://jsbin.com/ifawez/18/edit**

Comment: 80% of 100px is 80px, not 10px

Comment: If you're using media queries you can mix set widths with percentage widths.

Comment: This question is really too broad for SO.  The reality is that media queries aren't a good way to massage generic widgets like that.  You're looking for CSS where the content dictates its size, and there isn't that much of it available at the moment (Multi-Column module, Flexbox) and all you can really do is control flow/positioning, not anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cimmanon's comment cleared things out for me.
The problem is with lack of HTML/CSS "tools" available at the moment. Since responsiveness came into play fairly recently there are not a lot of CSS-native tools to accommodate changes in dimensions.

For instance media-queries exclusively work with width of window/document and not of other elements such as divs.

The solution I currently employ is using Javascript to determine width of a div and resize accordingly.
What I resize is the number of columns I want to display (I use Multi-Column module as suggested by cimmanon) which is pretty stable on webkit browsers. Since it is all done in Javascript (and jQuery's Sizzle) I keep an array of sizes like so:

```
 var widthArray = [
    {min:0,   max:250,  columns:1, secondary:false},
    {min:251, max:350,  columns:1, secondary:true },
    {min:351, max:479,  columns:1, secondary:true },
    //more div sizes
 ];
 // more code here
 $(element).css({
    "column-count": object.columns,
    "-moz-column-count": object.columns,
    "-webkit-column-count": object.columns
});
```

This is sort of like media-queries, but allows to work with width of html elements, not screen size alone.

Additionally I follow the way jQuery UI displays its components: using position relative/absolute.

```
.outer_div {
    position: relative;
}
.inner_div_with_elements {
    position:   absolute;
    z-index: 1010;
    width: 99%;    
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
.inner_components_displayable {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.inner_components_hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

### So in Summary:

1. Media queries alone work with size of screen, and resizing of any inner element can be done in percentages to the screen size. They can be of huge help, but you turn into making your components work either with percentages based off screen, or specifying something like min-height and !important (as suggested by @Octavian)
2. Javascript manipulation of elements is currently easier, but is a costlier alternative (jQuery SIzzle is pretty slow)
3. A lot of libraries (ex. jQuery UI) use Javascript together with position relative/absolute to make sure their components/plug-ins will work nicely on all users' screen sizes.
4. I ended up combining position with javascript to emulate media-queries and multi-column design at the same time for responsiveness.

Thanks everyone who participated!

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, the main issue here is that it can potentially become too small based on where the code is located.

So why not just add a min-width property with !important? That way you can still base the size off of the parent container, but be sure that it doesn't get too small and ugly.

Potentially, you could even have a script to base the width off of the parent div and the min-width off of the screen size.